# Setting an image to an imageCache to the beginning of the imageCache and not the end

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, object, caching

I set an object to the imageCache with this:

```
    self.picPostPicImageCache.setObject(UIImage(data:imageData)!,forKey: urlString as NSString)
                          }
```

This is used in a tableview like so:

```
    let cell : ImagePostTableViewCell = BarSelectedTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImagePostTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImagePostTableViewCell
        if let PicPostCacheImage = picPostPicImageCache.object(forKey: picPostPicUrlArray[indexPath.row] as NSString) { if let PicProPicCacheImage = picPostProPicImageCache.object(forKey: picPostProPicUrlArray[indexPath.row] as NSString) {

            cell.userImagePostView.image = PicPostCacheImage
            cell.userImageView.image = PicProPicCacheImage
            }
        } else {
            cell.userImagePostView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: picPostPicUrlArray[indexPath.row] as String), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "defaultPropic"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveLoad])
            cell.userImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: picPostProPicUrlArray[indexPath.row] as String), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "defaultPropic"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveLoad])

        }
```

The problem I run into is when I want to add a new photo to the cache. Currently, I use the same method of adding a new photo like this.

```
     self.picPostPicImageCache.setObject(UIImage(data:imageData)!,forKey: urlString as NSString)// new photo
```

However, this adds it to the end of the cache and displays the image at the bottom of tableview as opposed to the top. I would like to add it to the beginning of the cache. Is there any possible way of doing this without deleting the elements in the cache and reloading?